# FCM push notification to all devices which will be filtered on client side

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Okay, I know the question may sound stupid. I’m building an app where there are pages that publish posts and users can subscribe/unsubscribe to those pages.

The goal here is to find a way to send notifications whenever a new post is published but only to the subscribed users. I though that I can do this by sending a push notification to all the devices on my app whenever the “Posts” reference is updated on Firebase database, and then choose whether to show this notification or not if the user is subscribed (on client side)

Is this a good idea? And if yes, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good idea?

Yes, the idea is not bad. However, filtering notification to be shown in client side is done in many cases.

> And if yes, how can I accomplish that?

I hope you already have a login or authentication system using Firebase authentication or any other server side authentication. When you have this, you might have already considered sending a push registration id to your server or firebase when a user signs up in your application and save it in your firebase database.

Now when its time to send a push notification, you are planning to send the push notification to all of your registered devices and you want to filter the notification will be shown or nor in the client side.

This can be achieved by keeping a flag in the client side, for example a `SharedPreference` having the id or tag of the last post. If you have an incremental id for each post, then it will be a lot easier to implement. When a user launches your application, it pulls the posts from your firebase database as I can think of. Just save the latest id of the post in your `SharedPreference` and when a push is received, match the id of the post that came along with the push notification with the latest id stored locally.

If the id received via push notification is greater than the id stored in your `SharedPreference`, you will show the notification in system tray and the notification will not be shown otherwise.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not quite my case, but it certainly gave me lot's of ideas!!

Comment: Great to know that I could help. Please let me know here if you post any other question regarding your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can push notification to only subscribed users if you are maintaining a list of subscribed users FCM token in your database

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, what you would need to do is that maintain different database tables for all pages where users are inserted when they subscribe to that particular group/table.

So, let's suppose when a person subscribes to the page containing information about Sports, you add him to that group. Later, when you are sending update/notifications related to 'Sports' you would only send those push notifications to the user-tokens in 'Sports' table.

In this way, only relevant subscribers would receive those push notifications.